Run ansi-term in a new frame
I have the following in my .emacs :
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("\\`\\*e?shell" display-buffer-pop-up-frame))

And it opens shell or eshell buffer in the new frame when I run M-x shell or M-x eshell. However it does not seem to work for ansi-term :
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("\\`\\*ansi-term" display-buffer-pop-up-frame))

What am I doing wrong, is the regexp incorrect?

I can reproduce this. I think the regex is correct, but somehow display-buffer does not obey this entry. If I do M-x ansi-term  first and then do (display-buffer-pop-up-frame "*ansi-term*" display-buffer-alist) I do get it to pop up in a new frame. You may need a display-buffer expert here...

Yes, it looks like display-buffer needs to have it opened in a window?
I'm reading https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html and it says that creating a new frame is the last option.

ansi-term calls switch-to-buffer rather than pop-to-buffer or display-buffer, and so the display-buffer machinery isn't invoked.
One option would be to customize switch-to-buffer-obey-display-actions or let-bind it in a custom wrapper.
Untested:
(define-advice ansi-term (:around (orig-fun &rest args) my-display-buffer)
  "Advice for `ansi-term'.  Obey display actions.

Remove with:
\(advice-remove \\='ansi-term \\='ansi-term@my-display-buffer)"
  (let ((switch-to-buffer-obey-display-actions t))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

